# IM Client Integration with Outlook

Tags: outlook

I  am trying to understand the procedure of Integration the IM Client with Outlook 2010. The below link is used for this :-

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900715.aspx

Outlook is able to reach the CreateInstance method of my implementation.

1. If I have the Lync Client installed than the controls reaches till GetInterfaceMethod, in which I am returning the object of ILyncClient.

There is no progress after this. Following error is showed in the outlook debugs :

MsoIMProviderFactory--HrEnsureDefaultIMAppRegKeys Succeeded opening reg key (HKCU-SOFTWARE\IM Providers)

CMsoIMProviderFactory--HrEnsureDefaultIMAppRegKeys Succeeded querying reg key (HKCU-SOFTWARE\IM Providers-DefaultIMApp-IMapp)

CMsoIMProviderFactory--HrEnsureDefaultIMProcessRegKey Succeeded opening reg key (HKCU-SOFTWARE\IM Providers\IMapp)

CMsoIMProviderFactory--HrEnsureDefaultIMProcessRegKey Succeeded opening reg key (HKLM-SOFTWARE\IM Providers\IMapp)

CMsoIMProviderFactory--WhichMessengerInProcessList Using (IMapp) process name for search

CMsoIMProviderFactory--WhichMessengerInProcessList Using (IMapp) process name for search

Guys please give your feedback regarding the same ?????

2. If I don’t have Lync Client Installed than control never reaches to Authentication Method.

A. Do we need to implement the IMessenger interface also ?

B. If yes then please show some pointers on how to do that ?

Any pointers to resolve this would be helpful.

For building the COM server we are using out of process COM example(CSExeCOMServer). I had tried the same setup with outlook 2013 also.  In this too the output remains the same.

Environment :-

Windows 7 Service Pack1 .

Outlook 2010 & 2013.

Answer (score 0):

1. You would always need Lync installed in you machine since the interfaces which you used in your code are defined by Lync. If you want to remove this dependency then you will have to register your typelibrary (.tlb) in the system. To generate .tlb you need an .idl file which you can explore on net how to get.
2. If you want to be an IM Provider then you need not implement this IMessenger interface. But if you want to work in Legacy provider way you will have to implement this interfaces(this i had not tried).
3. And to resolve your issue I would need the code snippet as how you are defining the LyncClient class. Once you share that then I would try to help you.

I was able to make this work in both outlook 2010 & 2013 but then I used C# way of implementing the COM Server.